# Putting popover on noUiSlider handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, nouislider

I am working on using noUislider as a slider.  One thing I want to do is upon hovering the handle you can have a popover and upon clicking it another action inside the popover will occur.  How can I target the particular handle, noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower,  inside of a slider to trigger the popover?

To clarify: This slider's handle lower is an embedded child in the slider.

```
<div id="slider1" style="width: 400px; margin: 0px auto 30px;" class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover1" data-original-title="" > <div class="noUi-base"><div class="noUi-connects"></div><div class="noUi-origin" style="transform: translate(-100%, 0px); z-index: 5;">
<div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower" data-handle="0" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="100.0" aria-valuenow="0.0" aria-valuetext="0.00"></div></div>
<div class="noUi-origin" style="transform: translate(0%, 0px); z-index: 4;"><div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-upper" data-handle="1" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="100.0" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuetext="100.00"></div></div></div></div>

$('#slider1 .noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower').popover({trigger: "manual", container: 'body', title: "Hello", content: "Test"})
    .on('mouseenter', function() { enterShow('slider1')})
    .on('mouseleave', function() { exitHide('slider1')})
    .on('click', function() { clickToggle('sliderx1')});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I asked and so I'm going to detail it here.

First, you want to ensure that you have a document.ready code as we will aid in finding the handles.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

noUiSlider does not load everything until it finds the sliders and confirms its there making other scripting events intracable.

The next thing I did was to find each instance of the class no noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower and tag each one of these handles based upon their id

```
$('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').attr('data-placement','right');
for (qwr =0; qwr < $('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').length; qwr++){
    var holdid = $('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').eq(qwr).parent().closest("div[id]")[0].id;
    //console.log(holdid);
    holdid = holdid.replace("nslider", "slider");
    //console.log(holdid);
    $('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').eq(qwr).attr('id',holdid);   
    }
```

Then I made sure to intialize the state for the id

```
$('#slider1').data('state', 'hover');
```

Finally, I placed my bootstrap information

```
$('#slider1 .noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower').popover({trigger: "manual", container: 'body', title: "Hello", content: "Test"})
    .on('mouseenter', function() { enterShow('slider1')})
    .on('mouseleave', function() { exitHide('slider1')})
    .on('click', function() { clickToggle('slider1')});
```

Put it all together:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
$('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').attr('data-placement','right');
for (qwr =0; qwr < $('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').length; qwr++){
    var holdid = $('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').eq(qwr).parent().closest("div[id]")[0].id;
    //console.log(holdid);
    holdid = holdid.replace("nslider", "slider");
    //console.log(holdid);
    $('div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower').eq(qwr).attr('id',holdid);   
    }
$('#slider1').data('state', 'hover');

$('#slider1 .noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower').popover({trigger: "manual", container: 'body', title: "Hello", content: "Test"})
    .on('mouseenter', function() { enterShow('slider1')})
    .on('mouseleave', function() { exitHide('slider1')})
    .on('click', function() { clickToggle('slider1')});
});
```

That should do.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
// target the particular handle    
const handle = document.querySelector('.noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower');

handle.onmouseenter = function () {
    // code to insert popover HTML goes here
}

handle.onmouseleave = function () {
    // code to remove popover HTML goes here
}
```

I'm not going to do the "popover" HTML for you, because that could be literally anything. I recommend using [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) for this. Good luck.

Comment: I had tried attempting the query selector but it will not recognize the slider it's currently on.